# Issue with animating multiple views inside ForEach using .animation(animation, value: ...)

Tags: swift, macos, animation, swiftui

I have a list of expandable cards inside a LazyVStack. I have a separate View defined for a card and populate the list inside the LazyVStack using ForEach. When I tap on any card, it expands to reveal more information. As it expands, **the cards around it should shift up/down with animation**.

When I use `.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3))` on the entire VStack of the individual card view, each card acts as it should - the tapped one expands and the other ones shift around smoothly.

[image]

But I get the warning - `'animation' was deprecated in macOS 12.0: Use withAnimation or animation(_:value:) instead.` So I tried using  `.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3), value: isExpanded)` where isExpanded is toggled inside onTapGesture. However, that results in only the tapped card animating and all the rest of the cards just shifting around abruptly with no animation.

From what I understand, the cards that are not tapped don’t know that something has changed, so no animation is triggered. I’m not sure what value to track so that the .animation can trigger for all cards and not just the tapped one.
[image]

How do I keep the desired behavior from `.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3))` without using the deprecated syntax?

Here's simplified Swift Playground code that replecates this issue:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

struct listItem: Codable, Hashable, Equatable {
    let status: String
    let date: String
    let statusDescription: String
    let caseId: String
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    let listOfItems: [listItem]
    
    init() {
        let item1 = listItem(status: "In Progress", date: "2023/04/17 10:30", statusDescription: "Item processing started.", caseId: "CASE123")
        let item2 = listItem(status: "Completed", date: "2023/04/16 14:45", statusDescription: "Item successfully processed.", caseId: "CASE124")
        let item3 = listItem(status: "Pending", date: "2023/04/18 09:00", statusDescription: "Item awaiting processing.", caseId: "CASE125")
        let item4 = listItem(status: "Failed", date: "2023/04/15 18:10", statusDescription: "Item processing failed due to an error.", caseId: "CASE126")
        listOfItems = [item1, item2, item3, item4]
    }

    var body: some View {
        LazyVStack(spacing: 8) {
            ForEach(listOfItems, id: \.self) { listItem in
                ListCard(entry: listItem)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300)
    }
}

struct ListCard: View {
    let entry: listItem
    @State private var isExpanded: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12) {
            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                    Text("\(entry.status)")
                        .font(.headline)
                    
                    Text(entry.date)
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        .allowsHitTesting(false)
                        
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(isExpanded ? 180 : 0))
                    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3), value: isExpanded)
            }
            if isExpanded {
                Text("\(entry.statusDescription)")
                    .font(.body)
                    .lineSpacing(4)
                    .transition(.opacity)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .background(.gray.opacity(0.10))
        .cornerRadius(8)
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3), value: isExpanded)
        .onTapGesture {
            isExpanded.toggle()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

I tried tracking the tap event on the entire LazyVStack and passing it to ListCard so that all cards know that some card has been expanded, but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by passing a custom onTap closure that tells the view whether it's the one expanding by using its unique IDs:

1. In the modified ContentView, I added an @State variable expandedCardID with an initial value of nil (no card is initially expanded)
2. Then, in the ForEach loop I pass two additional parameters to ListView: isExpanded and onTap

   - The isExpanded parameter is a boolean value that checks if the current listItem's caseId is equal to the expandedCardID. If it is equal, the card is expanded (isExpanded is true); otherwise, it's not expanded (isExpanded is false).
   - onTap closure executes when the card is tapped. withAnimation function creates the animation. The expandedCardID is updated with a conditional expression:

     - If the expandedCardID is equal to the current listItem.caseId, it means that the expanded card has been tapped again, and we should collapse it by setting expandedCardID to nil.
     - If the expandedCardID is not equal to the current listItem.caseId, it means that a different card has been tapped, and we should update the expandedCardID to the tapped listItem.caseId.
     - This ensures that only one card is expanded at a time, and the other cards are aware of which card is currently expanded.

Here's the updated code that works. Hope this helps someone else down the road!

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

struct listItem: Codable, Hashable, Equatable {
    let status: String
    let date: String
    let statusDescription: String
    let caseId: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let listOfItems: [listItem]
    @State private var expandedCardID: String?
    
    init() {
        let item1 = listItem(status: "In Progress", date: "2023/04/17 10:30", statusDescription: "Item processing started.", caseId: "CASE123")
        let item2 = listItem(status: "Completed", date: "2023/04/16 14:45", statusDescription: "Item successfully processed.", caseId: "CASE124")
        let item3 = listItem(status: "Pending", date: "2023/04/18 09:00", statusDescription: "Item awaiting processing.", caseId: "CASE125")
        let item4 = listItem(status: "Failed", date: "2023/04/15 18:10", statusDescription: "Item processing failed due to an error.", caseId: "CASE126")
        listOfItems = [item1, item2, item3, item4]
    }

    var body: some View {
        LazyVStack(spacing: 8) {
            ForEach(listOfItems, id: \.self) { listItem in
                ListCard(entry: listItem, isExpanded: expandedCardID == listItem.caseId, onTap: {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3)) {
                        expandedCardID = expandedCardID == listItem.caseId ? nil : listItem.caseId
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300)
    }
}

struct ListCard: View {
    let entry: listItem
    let isExpanded: Bool
    let onTap: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12) {
            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                    Text("\(entry.status)")
                        .font(.headline)
                    
                    Text(entry.date)
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        .allowsHitTesting(false)
                        
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(isExpanded ? 180 : 0))
                    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3), value: isExpanded)
            }
            if isExpanded {
                Text("\(entry.statusDescription)")
                    .font(.body)
                    .lineSpacing(4)
                    .transition(.opacity)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .background(.gray.opacity(0.10))
        .cornerRadius(8)
        .onTapGesture(perform: onTap)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```